# bind variables not allowed for data definition operations (CREATE A VIEW TABLE)

Tags: oracle

```
CREATE VIEW "KIR_V_KAS_MASUK_KET" ("KODE_KAS", "NIS", "NAMA", "KELAS", "JURUSAN", "PERIODE", "TOTAL_PEMBAYARAN", "TOTAL_WAJIB_BAYAR", "KETERANGAN") as
    SELECT DISTINCT
KMH.KODE_KAS,
KA.NIS,
KA.NAMA,
KA.KELAS,
KA.JURUSAN,
(SELECT PERIODE FROM KIR_KAS_MASUK_HEAD WHERE KODE_KAS=:P16_KODE_KAS) PERIODE,
TO_CHAR((SELECT SUM(PEMBAYARAN)  FROM KIR_KAS_MASUK_DETAIL WHERE KODE_KAS = :P16_KODE_KAS), '999,999,999') TOTAL_PEMBAYARAN,
TO_CHAR(WAJIB_BAYAR * (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM KIR_ANGGOTA WHERE STATUS != 'TIDAK AKTIF'), '999,999,999') TOTAL_WAJIB_BAYAR,
KMD.KETERANGAN
FROM
KIR_ANGGOTA KA,
KIR_KAS_MASUK_HEAD KMH,
KIR_KAS_MASUK_DETAIL KMD
WHERE
KMD.KODE_KAS=KMH.KODE_KAS
AND
KMD.NIS=KA.NIS
/
```

i hope someone will correct my syntax in line 10/45 because is says "Error at line 10/45: ORA-01027: bind variables not allowed for data definition operations". I really have no idea how to fix the syntax

i need to create a view table so that i can create this form [the result that i wanted to build using the code above this text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylNXT.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're getting the error is because you have bind variables inside your view (e.g. `(SELECT PERIODE FROM KIR_KAS_MASUK_HEAD WHERE KODE_KAS=:P16_KODE_KAS)`) which, as per the error, is not allowed inside a view definition.

What you can do instead is create a context (which needs to be associated with a package) - see [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CREATE-CONTEXT.html#GUID-FDF62812-A884-479C-9C1B-5BD6DDEFE7FA) for an example of how to do that, assign a value to that context and then use that in your view .

You would then have a procedure in the associated package that sets the specific context value you're interested in using `dbms_session.set_context`.

E.g. something like:

```
create or replace context your_context using your_schema.your_package;

create or replace package your_package
as
  ...
  procedure set_your_view_context_value (view_context_value);
  ...
end your_package;
/

create or replace package body your_package
as
  ...
  procedure set_your_view_context_value (view_context_value)
  is
  begin
    dbms_session.set_context('YOUR_CONTEXT', 'ATTRIBUTE_NAME', view_context_value);
  end set_your_view_context_value;
  ...
end your_package;
/

create or replace view your_view
as
select sys_context('YOUR_CONTEXT', 'ATTRIBUTE_NAME')
from   dual;
```

Comment: i'm sorry but i am still new in sql and i don't know some of the syntax you just wrote but i get a grasp of what do you mean. So if i change the snytax at line 10 like this 
(SELECT DISTINCT PERIODE FROM KIR_KAS_MASUK_HEAD WHERE KODE_KAS=v('P16_KODE_KAS')) PERIODE, is it correct

Comment: so you have a bind variable (`:P16_KODE_KAS`) that is referenced twice in your query. Once you have set up the context, and created a procedure to set the value of your context, you would create the view and reference the context value like `sys_context('YOUR_CONTEXT_NAME', 'YOUR_ATTRIBUTE_NAME')`. Then, before you query the view, instead of setting the value of the bind variable, you set the context value by calling the procedure you created earlier.